# User based permissions/scopes in Spring oAuth2

Tags: spring, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

In my current setup I have standalone spring oAuth2 server, standalone resource server and angularJs app with reverse proxy.

On the authentication server side I have register 2 clients (web-app and internal client for service communication). I correctly receive client scopes and Users roles.

**Question 1**
I need different permission (e.g. scopes) per user not client (web-app, mobile,...)

I tried providing my own ClientsDetailService where I would build ClientDetails for each user, but only thing I receive is client id ("web-app") and I have no way of knowing which user is logged in.

Is there a way to inject user context?

related [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345466/mapping-user-roles-to-oauth2-scopes-authorities)

**Question 2** I can somehow work around this if I put all of the available permissions in the JWT and do the "hasPermission(...)" logic on the resource servers. Basically client app works in N scopes and server based on the Users role builds list of permissions and creates JWT. But...

- What happens when I remove users permission? Is the JWT invalidated?
- What is the oAuth workflow in this scenario? (will refresh_token get updated permissions or user has to enter credentials again?)
- Since this seems like bad practice, is there better solution?

**Question 3** Is there a standard way of implementing more granular permission logic with spring oauth2? (think of 100+ different permissions with method level security)

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Basically all of the 3 questions boil down to one. Does spring-security-oath2 allow different scopes per User instead of Client and is this a good practice? I have code examples but, they would not provide any more insight in the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I finally managed to map custom scopes per user using TokenEnhancer as follows:

```
public class AuthorityTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {

@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();

    final ImmutableMap<String, Object> additionalInfo = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
            .put("authorities", user.getAuthorities())
            .build();

    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setScope(user.getPermissions());

    return accessToken;
}}
```

With this approach I can get currently logged in user and update scopes based on user permissions.

But still I don't know whether this is good practice or not.

Comment: I have exactly the same question. I'd like to know whether this is the good practice or the user scopes are supposed to be set somewhere else other than ClientDetails service