# Using "spring-security-oauth2," can custom parameters be passed in the "Authorization Phase" of OAuth2?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing the **Authorization Code** flow + **JWT**.

I would like to know if and how it may be possible to add additional custom parameters to the *Authorization Phase* of the flow.

Essentially, I am looking to do the following:

1. When redirecting the user to the `/oauth/authorize` endpoint I would like to
   pass in an additional parameter (customPar*emphasized text*ameter) in the

> GET url
>       http://.../oauth/authorize?...*customParameter*=[VALUE] such that
>       VALUE is dynamic

2. I will need to retrieve VALUE when creating the
   **JWT**, populating the **JWT** with that VALUE

Is this possible? How can I implement?

Answer (score 0):

My idea is add your parameter during *AuthorizationRequest* in custom *OAuth2RequestFactory* at *createAuthorizationRequest* method like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345466/mapping-user-roles-to-oauth2-scopes-authorities):

```
@Override
public AuthorizationRequest createAuthorizationRequest(Map<String, String> authorizationParameters) {
    //here
    authorizationParameters.put("your", "parameter");
    //
    AuthorizationRequest request = super.createAuthorizationRequest(authorizationParameters);
    if (securityContextAccessor.isUser()) {
        request.setAuthorities(securityContextAccessor.getAuthorities());
    }
      return request;
}
```

You can populate request and inject Request or Session in your custom OAuth2RequestFactory and retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

The custom parameters passed will also  get stored in **HttpSession**.
Below is sample code to retrieve them.

```
HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
DefaultSavedRequest savedRequest = (DefaultSavedRequest) 
           httpSession.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST");
Map<String, String[]> parametersMap =  savedRequest.getParameterMap();
```